# json_decode в старых версиях PHP

Tags: php

Есть сервер на котором установлена версия php 4.4, переносить на более высокую версию пхп нет смысла-очень старый сайт. Прикрутил смс шлюз, переписал чуть класы для работы с ним. Столкнулся с проблемой что нет функций json_decode и json_encode. Может кто-то сталкивался и сможет помоч найти решение проблемы? Спасибо.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, вы предлагаете скопипастить инструкцию по установке PECL-пакета? pecl install json? Или же награда предназначена сугубо для стимулирования FreeDooM?

Comment: а почему ответ не исчерпывающий?реально помогло...пишлось правда чуть переделать под свою конкретную задачу...считаю вполне нормальным ответом

Comment: @Мелкий награда была для любого, кто возьмет на себя труд привести ответ в порядок.

Comment: @ПобежимовБорис ответ был просто ссылкой, поэтому конечно не исчерпывающим.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Придется прикручивать вручную:

Используя библиотеку ниже, нужно проверить и определить, если методов преобразования нет:

```
if (!function_exists('json_decode')) {
    function json_decode($content, $assoc=false) {
        require_once 'classes/JSON.php';
        if ($assoc) {
            $json = new Services_JSON(SERVICES_JSON_LOOSE_TYPE);
        }
        else {
            $json = new Services_JSON;
        }
        return $json->decode($content);
    }
}

if (!function_exists('json_encode')) {
    function json_encode($content) {
        require_once 'classes/JSON.php';
        $json = new Services_JSON;
        return $json->encode($content);
    }
}
```

**Ссылка на библиотеку:**
http://mike.teczno.com/JSON/JSON.phps

**Взято с:**
http://www.epigroove.com/blog/how-to-use-json-in-php-4-or-php-51x

Comment: Спасибо) именно то что надо

Answer (score 3):

Исходный [PECL пакет](https://pecl.php.net/package/json), который потом переместили в ядро PHP, заявляет поддержку от PHP 4.3. Попробуйте так его и поставить.